# How to pass an array with a key to the argument of a function? (Working with multi-dimensional arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays

This may not be a good question, but it does makes sense(atleast to me, it does.)
Suppose I have a multi-dimensional array called `temporaryFrequency`. Now, I want to write a function which will take one argument --> `frequencyArray[number]`. This will be more clear from the code:

JS:

```
function getMaxTemporaryFrequency(frequencyArray[number]){
    var maxOutofThese = frequencyArray[number][0];
        for(var i = 0; i < frequencyArray[number].length; i++){
            if(frequencyArray[number][i] > maxOutofThese)
                maxOutofThese = frequencyArray[number][i];
        }
    return maxOutofThese;
}
```

This is the function which will return the maximum frequency from a sub-array of an array. Now, I will execute the following code to call the function:

```
//This is to get the max out of the temporary frequencies
    for(var n = 0; n < temporaryFrequency.length; n++){
        var maximumTempFrequency + (n + 1) = getMaxTemporaryFrequency(temporaryFrequency[n]);
    }
```

Now, I have one more question attached to this. Can variable names be concatenated, like a did here? For example, for each loop count, I want to make variables : `maximumTempFrequency1` , `maximumTempFrequency2` , `maximumTempFrequency3` and so on.

Now, this call of the function passes the nth element of the `temporaryFrequency` array to the function, which should return the greatest value from that nth sub-array. But, that is not working.

So, to summarise my question:

> 1) Can we pass an array with a key to function, like I did here? If
>   no, is there any way to do it?
>
> 2) Can we concatenate strings to make a variable name, like I did in
>   the 'for' loop? If no, is there any other method

*NOTE: For this question, viewers don't need to know the contents of the `temporaryFrequency` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight answer to your two questions are No.

The syntax `function getMaxTemporaryFrequency(frequencyArray[number]) { ... }` is not valid. The parser is expecting an identifier for the parameter name, and identifiers can't have brackets in them `[` or `]`. This results in the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Similarly, your variable name is also syntactically invalid.  `var maximumTempFrequency + (n + 1) = //anything` results in

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
```

To answer your follow up questions of How to make it work, for the first question you can pass the dereferenced array member to the function when you call it (instead of when you declare it).

```
var frequencyArray = []; // fill it with your values
var number = 0; // or whatever number you want

function getMaxTemporaryFrequency(arr){
    var maxOutofThese = arr[0];
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] > maxOutofThese)
                maxOutofThese = arr[i];
        }
    return maxOutofThese;
}
function getMaxTemporaryFrequency(frequencyArray[number]);
```

For the latter one, you want to store the results to an array, like this:

```
//This is to get the max out of the temporary frequencies
var maximumTempFrequency = [];
for(var n = 0; n < temporaryFrequency.length; n++){
    maximumTempFrequency[n+1] = getMaxTemporaryFrequency(temporaryFrequency[n]);
}
```

Note that your syntax `getMaxTemporaryFrequency(temporaryFrequency[n])` is an example of what I put in the first code block above.

Comment: thnx a lot for the help